# parsing a xml using java code palette in tibco

Tags: java, tibco

I want *to convert string xml* to *tree structure format* using **java code palette**. I tried very hard to solve this.
But i didnt know *how to write the code* in *java code palette*.

Please share any one has solution for this.Plzzz help me..

Comment: Why would you need a java code activity for that? To turn an xml string into a parsed tree, you could simply use the "Parse XML" activity. http://tinypic.com/r/28v3r/8

Answer (score 0):

You can write java code using eclipse. Create a jar once you implemented your logic in java. Place that jar under tibco/bw/lib. In TIBCO designer, using java method activity you should be able to access the jar and related method. If you need more details then please refer document (designer and BW). Let me know if steps I mentioned resolved your issue.

~Hems